# How to increase SPI buffer on Google Coral?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, led, google-coral

Using Google Coral Dev on Mendel linux:
I am attempting to control an RGB LED strip using SPI. However, I am encountering an issue where the SPI buffer size is too small, and I am unable to control more than six LEDs without the SPI data being preempted or the OS interrupting the signal.

My first attempt to resolve this was with the following commands:

```
sudo su
cd /sys/module/spidev/parameters
chmod 666 bufsiz
echo 65534 > bufsiz
```

However, I received a permission denied error. I then tried to create the file `/boot/cmdline.txt` and added the following line:

```
spidev.bufsiz=32768
```

Upon rebooting, I checked `/sys/module/spidev/parameters/bufsiz`

```
4096
```

The same signal preemption still exists.

It doesn't seem like the Coral will allow me to update the SPI buffer size. I'm not sure if this is a hardware limitation or not, but I can't find a workaround.

My main concern is controlling a LED strip with 50 LEDs. Any advice on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

I was referencing https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x which used the SPI buffer fix to solve the issue.